# Select row with most non-key information for each group

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

Okay, I have a table with some junk data and no unique identifier column. Let me give you an example of the table I'm working with:

```
     A    |   B   |  C   |        D         |   E  |
  --------------------------------------------------
1.  Fiona | Smith | NULL | 2152 Cherry Lane | CA   |
2.  Fiona | Smith | NULL | NULL             | NULL |
3.  Bill  | NULL  | ACME | 2903 Center Road | WA   |
4.  Bill  | NULL  | ACME | NULL             | NULL |
5.  NULL  | NULL  | ABC  | 2300 Water St    | PA   |
6.  NULL  | NULL  | ABC  | 2300 Water St    | PA   |
7.  NULL  | NULL  | NULL | 3455 B Street    | CO   |
```

I need to write a SELECT statement that grabs only distinct rows. For example, take rows 1 and 2. They both obviously refer to the same person, but they're only partially duplicate. Out of those two, I want row 1 included in my SELECT statement because it contains the  most data in each column. Same goes for rows 3 and 4. Row 3 is the one I want included. For rows 5 and 6, it does not matter which one is selected since they both are exact duplicates. Row 7 would be included by default since it is distinct (meaning A, B and C, not just A and B).

Here's what I have tried:

```
SELECT A, B, C = MAX(D), MAX(E), 
FROM dbo.Data
GROUP BY A, B, C;
```

This seems to grab the unique rows I want, but the data is somehow placed into the wrong columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach treats D and E as equal:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
  A VARCHAR(32), 
  B VARCHAR(32), 
  C VARCHAR(32), 
  D VARCHAR(32), 
  E VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT @x VALUES
('Fiona', 'Smith', NULL,   '2152 Cherry Lane',  'CA'),
('Fiona', 'Smith', NULL,   NULL,                NULL),
('Bill',  NULL,    'ACME', '2903 Center Road',  'WA'),
('Bill',  NULL,    'ACME', NULL,                NULL),
(NULL  ,  NULL,    'ABC',  '2300 Water St',     'PA'),
(NULL  ,  NULL,    'ABC',  '2300 Water St',     'PA'),
(NULL  ,  NULL,    NULL,   '3455 B Street',     'CO'),
('Bob',   'Barker',NULL,   NULL,                NULL),
('Bob',   'Barker',NULL,   NULL,                'NY');

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT A,B,C,D,E, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (
    PARTITION BY A,B,C
    ORDER BY COALESCE(LEN(LEFT(D,1)),0) + COALESCE(LEN(LEFT(E,1)),0) DESC
  )
  FROM @x
)
SELECT A,B,C,D,E
FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Hey Aaron, thanks for the answer, it worked! I will definitely have to do some research to figure out what exactly this code is doing and why.

Comment: [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) allows you to apply ranking to rows (and groups of related rows, called partitions) based on criteria you define. In this case I knew you considered `A,B,C` to be your key, so this is what we partition on. Then it was a matter of determining how to define the most important row in each group. The COALESCE expression ensures that we get either 0 (for NULL or empty string) or 1 (for a populated value) for D and E. Highest value wins. If you want a tie-breaker you can add `,D DESC, E DESC` or the opposite depending on...

Comment: ...whether you prefer D or E in the case where one row has only D and another row has only E. I tried to demonstrate how this solution prefers a row with a value in E and not D over a row with no value in either.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining it. Can I ask one more thing? How do you insert the result of this query into another existing table?

Comment: Put an insert before the second-last line. `) INSERT dbo.othertable(cols) SELECT A,B,C,D,E ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT  A, B, C, D, E,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B,C
                               ORDER BY 
                                 CASE WHEN D IS NULL 
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE 1 END DESC) x
   FROM table1
)
SELECT A,B,C,D,E
FROM recordsList
WHERE x = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cc71/4)

Comment: This will potentially choose a row with less data in the case where D is null but E is not (see the additional sample rows in my answer).

Comment: @user1994209 you're welcome. the query is only based on your results. I assumed that if `D` is null and so is `E`. anyway, i'm glad `:D`

Comment: @JW - I have a quick question. Would this query treat D and E as equal if I added

CASE WHEN E IS NULL
THEN 0
ELSE 1 END DESC

Comment: if you mean `CASE WHEN D IS NULL 
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE 1 END DESC, CASE WHEN E IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC`. yes, but it orders `D` first then `E`.